# How to edit a .txt file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, text-editor, java.util.scanner

i think i can use "Scanner" to read a .txt file but how can i write or even create a new text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new text file

```
FileOutputStream object=new FileOutputStream("a.txt",true);
object.write(byte[]);
object.close();
```

This will create a file if not available and if a file is already available it will append data to it.

Comment: But that’s not very useful for writing *text*.

Answer (score 4):

This [Basic I/O and Files Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) should do the trick :)

Comment: in this link it teaches about a class called 'Path' but its not in jdk 6 .and i'm not sure that jdk 7 is released.
:?

Answer (score 1):

Create a java.io.FileOutputStream to write it. To write text, you can create a `PrintWriter` around it.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code example will create the text file if it doesn't exist, and if it does, it will overwrite it:

```
try {  
    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("c:/myfile.txt");  
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);  
    // Also could be written as follows on one line  
    // Printwriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename));  
    // Write text to file  
    out.println("This is some text I wrote");  
    out.close();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Hope it helps!